# Using with_items in Variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

In the below code I am using Ansible template, copying it to multiple locations. The template also has a variable in it : {{user}}. This should be replaced with - imail1,imail2,imail3,imail4 respectively. item.user is not getting substituted for some reason but not throwing any error. I have looked at multiple options like defining it as dict , but none of them fit here. Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
- name: Configure logback file for imail1
  template:
    src: /etc/ansible/roles/Buildout/files/logback.xml.j2
    dest: '/opt/"{{item.dest}}"/cassandra-meta/apache-cassandra-3.11.5/conf/logback.xml'
    owner: "{{item.owner}}"
    group: "{{item.group}}"
  vars:
    user: "{{item.user}}"
  with_items:
     - { dest: imail1, owner: imail1, group: imail1, user: imail1 }
     - { dest: imail2, owner: imail2, group: imail2, user: imail2 }
     - { dest: imail3, owner: imail3, group: imail3, user: imail3 }
     - { dest: imail4, owner: imail4, group: imail4, user: imail4 }
```

Adding snippet of template- logback.xml.j2 where {{user}} variable is used.

```
<configuration scan="true">
  <jmxConfigurator />

  <!-- No shutdown hook; we run it ourselves in StorageService after shutdown -->

  <!-- SYSTEMLOG rolling file appender to system.log (INFO level) -->

  <appender name="SYSTEMLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <file>/opt/{{user}}/cassandra-meta/log/system.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>/opt/{{user}}/cassandra-meta/log/system.log.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>20</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
```

Comment: Without an info on where you are using it, this will be hard to answer. You should provide at least an extract of the _logback.xml.j2_ template showing how you use it there.

Comment: To go further: there is absolutely nothing wrong with your loop and and your var declaration. Substituting `template: ....` wiht `debug: var=user` gives exactly what is expected. The problem must be in your template.

Comment: I have added a snippet of template I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my syntax. I had inverted commas with "{{item.dest}}".
The correct code is:

```
- name: Configure logback file for imail1
  template:
    src: /etc/ansible/roles/Buildout/files/logback.xml.j2
    dest: '/opt/{{item.dest}}/cassandra-meta/apache-cassandra-3.11.5/conf/logback.xml'
    owner: "{{item.owner}}"
    group: "{{item.group}}"
  vars:
    user: "{{item.user}}"
  with_items:
     - { dest: imail1, owner: imail1, group: imail1, user: imail1 }
     - { dest: imail2, owner: imail2, group: imail2, user: imail2 }
     - { dest: imail3, owner: imail3, group: imail3, user: imail3 }
     - { dest: imail4, owner: imail4, group: imail4, user: imail4 }
```